# Writing numerical lookup functions in python

Tags: python, function, user-defined-functions

In python, i would like to create several user-defined functions f(x) that are defined only at integer values x = i, where i ranges from 1 to several hundred. The functions themselves cannot be expressed as analytical or logical formulae but the values f(i) are known for all values i of the support range and so could be written as a table of pairs of values i, f(i).

Although i have written quite a few functions in python using def ..., I am still a python newbiwe, and i do not yet know how to efficiently code a function that must inherently use some form of numerical lookup table.  I seek your assistance with an example of what would be appropriate code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary e.g.

```
LOOKUP = {
    0: 100,
    1: 101,
    3: 102,
    9: 103,
}
def f(x):
    return LOOKUP[x]
```

Comment: You could hide the dictionary inside the function. And perhaps return a nice error for values of `x` out of range.

Comment: But then you'd have the cost of creating it every time the function was called. From the OP, it sounds like the dictionary may be quite big.

Comment: If the lookup table is supposed to be internal to a module, it is customary to prefix its name with an underscore; so `_lookup` instead of `LOOKUP`. Another thing to think about is if you want to handle possible `KeyError` exceptions inside the function.

Comment: From the OP: To me, as a naieve python newb, Daniel & Tom's solutions appear equivalent. In the current desired implementation, i takes values 1 to 400 and f(i) values are floating point numbers. Tichodroma's comment about returning an error value is also potentially useful, although I don't quite understand what was meant by "hiding the dictionary ...". Please elaborate.

Comment: @TonyMorland: He just means writing the giant `LOOKUP` dict inside `f` instead of outside.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want a function for this. A mapping in Python is expressed via a dictionary.

```
mapping = {
    1: 300,
    3: 990,
    45: 267,
    # etc
}

result = mapping[value]
```

Comment: You should do a Python tutorial: this is pretty basic stuff. How you handle it depends on what you want to do: if you have a default you want to return if there is no match, you can do `mapping.get(value, default_value)`.

Comment: Apologies for my simplistic beginners questions which are obviously way below the standard of other people on this site, but we all have to start somewhere and my thanks to you & all who helped.

Comment: It was supposed to be a sincere recommendation, not an insult: you really would benefit from doing a tutorial.

Comment: Yes, i agree, and i do appreciate the assistance that you have provided.